# Intel Intrinsics Guide relative error definition

Tags: x86, floating-point, precision, intrinsics, avx

Some of the intel vector instrinsics are approximations for which the Intel Intrinsics Guide gives a maximum relative error. For example the [`_mm256_rcp_ps`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm256_rcp_ps&ig_expand=5568) intrinsic has a maximum relative error of 1.5*2^-12.

I assume the relative error is defined as `relErr = abs((estVal-trueVal)/trueVal)`.

But what if the true value is very small and the estimation 0?
For example for the reciprocal of -1.11604e+38, the intrinsic `_mm256_rcp_ps` gives an estimate of -0.0, while the true value is about -8.96021e-39 (which would be a denormalized float, does it have to do something with that?).
The relative error would then be 1, but the estimation would still be good. How can I gauge the quality of the estimation if the estimation is 0? How is the relative error in the Intrinsics Guide defined if the estimation is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intrinsics guide often leaves stuff out; it's mostly only useful for finding intrinsic names for asm instructions, and a brief summary of what they do.

**Yes, for normalized float results, the top 11 or 12 bits of the mantissa will be correct**, as specified by `|Relative Error| ≤ 1.5 ∗ 2^−12`

The asm manual also documents that it ignores the MXCSR bits FTZ (Flush To Zero) and DAZ (Denormals Are Zero), and always behaves basically like they were set: tiny (subnormal) inputs are treated as zero, and tiny results are also flushed to zero.

See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcpps - the Description section is specific about the details, and gives some guarantees / ranges on when the relative error might produce a subnormal result (flushed to zero) when the exact result would still be normalized.

> The RCPPS instruction is not affected by the rounding control bits in the MXCSR register. When a source value is a 0.0, an ∞ of the sign of the source value is returned. **A denormal source value is treated as a 0.0** (of the same sign). **Tiny results** (see Section 4.9.1.5, “Numeric Underflow Exception (`#U`)” in Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1) are always **flushed to 0.0, with the sign of the operand.**
>
> (Input values greater than or equal to `|1.11111111110100000000000B`∗2<sup>125</sup>`|` are guaranteed to not produce tiny results; input values less than or equal to `|1.00000000000110000000001B`∗2<sup>126</sup>`|` are guaranteed to produce tiny results, which are in turn flushed to 0.0; and input values in between this range may or may not produce tiny results, depending on the implementation.)

That last part about value-range limits seems backwards to me; the larger the input, the more tiny the output, so how can all inputs less than some number be guaranteed to produce tiny (subnormal) results?  I assume it literally is backwards, and all values with magnitude >= `1.00000000000110000000001B`∗2<sup>126</sup> are guaranteed to produce a `0` result via FTZ.